# No support for Asymptote in AUCTeX

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex, asymptote

I got a  problem with my Emacs/AUCTeX setup.  I'm using a lot of Asymptote graphics in my TeX documents, but there is a big problem to compile such documents inside of Emacs with AUCTeX. However I can compile those document from within Kile.

For Emacs/AUCTeX this workaround works:

1. call from Emacs pdflatex(compile latex)
2. manually from the shell: `asy filename-1.asy`
3. call from Emacs pdflatex(compile latex)

How can I tell AUCTeX to call the `asy` compiler automatically if needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) via AUCTeX which with some minor configuration can compile LaTeX with Asymptote figures.

According to [the Asymptote manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/asymptote/doc/asymptote.pdf) you can use `latexmk` to compile LaTeX files containing Asymptote figures with a single command (§7):

> An even better method for processing a `LaTeX` file with embedded
>   `Asymptote` code is to use the `latexmk` utility from
>   http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/ after putting the
>   contents of
>   http://asymptote.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/asymptote/trunk/asymptote/doc/latexmkrc
>   in a file `latexmkrc` in the same directory. The command
>
> ```
> latexmk -pdf latexusage
> ```
>
> will then call `Asymptote` automatically, recompiling only the figures
>   that have changed. Since each figure is compiled in a separate system
>   process, this method also tends to use less memory.

What this means is that if you add the following to your latexmkrc

```perl
$pdf_mode = 1;
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

and run

```
latexmk your_document
```

it will do all the necessary steps to produce a PDF of your LaTeX document with Asymptote figures. Such a command can be invoked via AUCTeX to do what you want, i.e. [`latexmk` can be called from AUCTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8026921/789593).